# How to add datetime as a dict value?

Tags: python-3.x, date-parsing

In `for` loop I'm parsing `datetime.datetime` objects like `2016-06-29 00:00:00` out of the string values of my dictionary. In order to have date information separately from the rest of exident data I'm trying to add these objects as a key-value pair to existing dict.

```
      for i in enumerate(my_list):
          date = dateparser.parse(i[1].get('exident_data')[0:8])
          my_list[date] = date
```

... but I fail and getting:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not datetime.datetime
```

How to do it? Can't find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Two things: create a new list in output and use a string as key value for this list and not datetime.datetime

Comment: I was a little bit confused by your answer since I do not understand what for it is good to create a new list here. I'm dealing only with new variable `date` in `for` loop... As you told, I changed the way I create new key-value pair...                                                                                                                
`def get_date(my_list):
    for i in enumerate(my_list):
        date = dateparser.parse(i[1].get('exident_data')[0:8])
        if date != None:
            date = date.date()
        i[1]['date'] = date
    print(my_list)`

Comment: Ok, I need to be more clear. Your problem is at the end your want to create a dictionary not a list (the key is not an int). You can't modify your list on dictionary, so you need to create a new dictionary with the date as key. I don't think you can have a datetime as key you need to take a string as key i.e. str (date).

Comment: Or, if you want just update your list, modify `my_list[date] = date` by `my_list[i[0]] = date`, because i [0] is the key of your list with enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
mydate = {}
mydate['day'] = today.day
mydate['month'] = today.month
mydate['year'] = today.year
mydate['hour'] = today.hour
```

Try [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Yes, It is possible, but this approach will make afterwards necessary to compile date from several values... I used `date = date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` to format date...